# Echo Date - Date turning to the next day before midnight

Tags: php, date

I inputted this code:

```
<?php echo date('l, F jS Y'); 
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Denver'); ?>
```

The date changes about 2 hours before midnight to the next day. I don't know what other steps to take to make it punctually accurate to the Mountain timezone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');` at the beginning of script.

Comment: Like this: `<?php echo date ('l, F jS Y')l; date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver'); ?>`

Comment: Like this:
`
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver'); 

echo date('l, F jS Y'); 
?>`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try it. I'll find out tonight! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting default time zone at the beginning of the script.

```
<?php 
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver'); 
   echo date('l, F jS Y'); 
?>
```

And you can check current default time zone by:

```
date_default_timezone_get();
```